# Как передать запрос API python

Tags: python, requests

Всем добрый день, есть задача добавить пользователя в Геткурс через API
Инфа с геткурса
Импорт пользователя находится по адресу:

```
https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/users
```

Для добавления пользователя необходимо передать действие add, секретный ключ и параметры добавляемого пользователя:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json; q=1.0, */*; q=0.1" 
"https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/users" -d "action=add&key={secret_key}&рarams={params}"
```

Параметры пользователя:

```
base64_encode
    {
        "user":{
            "email":"email",
            "phone":"телефон",
            "first_name":"имя",
            "last_name":"фамилия",
            "city":"город",
            "country":"страна",
            "group_name":[ // для добавления пользователя в группы
                "Группа1", // простое добавление в групп
                ["Группа2", "2018-08-01 21:21"], // добавление в группу с указанием произвольного момента
                ["Группа4", "2018-08-02"]
            ],
            "addfields":{"Доп.поле1":"значение","Доп.поле2":"значение"} // для добавления дополнительных полей пользователя
        },
        "system":{
            "refresh_if_exists":0, // обновлять ли существующего пользователя 1/0 да/нет
            "partner_email":"email партнера (для пользователя)*"
        },
        "session":{
            "utm_source":"",
            "utm_medium":"",
            "utm_content":"",
            "utm_campaign":"",
            "utm_group":"",
            "gcpc":"",
            "gcao":"",
            "referer":""
        }
    }
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
import base64
import requests
import json

account_name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
BASE_URL = f"https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/users"

user = {'email' : 'testapi@test.pro',
          'phone': '+333333333333'}
s = json.dumps(user)
user=base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))
print(s)
print(user)
params = {'action':'add','key':'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','params':user}   
response = requests.post(BASE_URL, params=params)
```

В результате пользователь не создается. Действие передается как параметр action, POST-запроса. Мне не совсем понятно как передать action, буду признателен за любую помощь. Параметры для действия передаются в формате JSON, закодированного в base64 в параметре params POST-запроса.

Comment: Скорее всего, параметры юзера должны в аргументе к запросу `data` или `json` передаваться

Comment: Спасибо большое, именно так и оказалось

Answer (score 0):

В итоге рабочий вариант выглядит так:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

# Установка параметров запроса
url = 'https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/users'
action = 'add'
secret_key = '{secret_key}'

# Установка параметров нового пользователя
user = {
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "phone": "+1 555 1234",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "city": "New York",
    "country": "USA",
    "group_name": ["Group1", ["Group2", "2018-08-01 21:21"]],
    "addfields": {"Custom Field 1": "Value 1", "Custom Field 2": "Value 2"}
}

# Установка параметров системы
system = {
    "refresh_if_exists": 0,
    "partner_email": ""
}

# Установка параметров сессии
session = {
    "utm_source": "",
    "utm_medium": "",
    "utm_content": "",
    "utm_campaign": "",
    "utm_group": "",
    "gcpc": "",
    "gcao": "",
    "referer": ""
}

# Кодирование параметров в JSON и base64
params = {
    "user": user,
    "system": system,
    "session": session
}
params_json = json.dumps(params).encode('utf-8')
params_base64 = base64.b64encode(params_json).decode('utf-8')

# Отправка POST-запроса
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json; q=1.0, */*; q=0.1'
}
payload = {
    'action': action,
    'key': secret_key,
    'params': params_base64
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# Печать результата
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```